# Ant common usage calling java methods

Tags: java, ant

What is the common usage of using ant to execute a java class or method.

I have multiple methods within on class that I need to call if ant run or restore are run. Both run and restore are methods of the same java class but, I cannot seem to get ant run to execute Class.beginExecution() and ant restore to execute Class.beginRestore()..

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about writing a JUnit Testcase and calling that from ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task? You need to give it a fully qualified name of a class with a main method, just as if you ran it from command line.

Comment: Does it have to be the main of a class? Can I not execute a specific method? Or do I do that by passing arguments into main to call the correct method?

Comment: For that you could write your own task. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Create a main method on this class which takes a parameter indicating the correct method, calls the main method and uses the Ant [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task.
2. Create a couple of dummy classes that have a main method that calls the correct method on your class and use the above.
3. Write your own [Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) that either calls this class, or just have this class extend the Ant task class (that will work if it doesn't need to extend anything else).
4. @sunnyjava's solution is very clever, to use the Ant [junit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task to call JUnit tests that call your class. I don't see a huge advantage over #2 above, but it will gain you that if you use JUnit 4+ you can just annotate the methods you need run with the @Test. The downside is there would be no way to distinguish between your before and and after within one class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write regular java class with main method and run it with the following ant task:

```
<target name="run_main" depends="dist" description="--> runs main method of class YourMainClass">
    <java classname="test.com.YourMainClass"
          failonerror="true"
          fork="true">
        <sysproperty key="DEBUG" value="true"/>
        <arg value="${basedir}/"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="all.project.class.path"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```